# TChangeTabAction FMX XE7 - what were Embarcadero thinking?

Tags: delphi, tabcontrol, firemonkey, delphi-xe7, actionlist

After adding a standard action of TChangeTabAction to my actionlist, 
I have written a function like this:

```
procedure TfrmMain.ChangeTab(TargetTab: TTabItem; Reverse: Boolean = False);
begin
  ChangeTabAction1.Tab := TargetTab;
  ChangeTabAction1.ExecuteTarget(Self);
end;
```

which I call like this:

```
 ChangeTab(tsNewTemplate) // slides left
 // stuff
 ChangeTab(tsLogin); // slides right
```

and later

```
ChangeTab(tsNewTemplate, True); // slides left
// stuff
ChangeTab(tsLogin, True); // slides right
```

And I'm still trying to figure out how to add the Reverse = True functionality to my function!

The problem is, with each call to `ChangeTabAction1.ExecuteTarget(Self);`, the `ChangeTabAction1.Direction` is automatically reversed! (toggled)

So when the tab changes from tsStartUp to tsNewTemplate, it shifts to the left, then it shifts to the right, then to the left and right and so on.

What I want it to do is

```
ChangeTab(tsNewTemplate) // slides left
// stuff
 ChangeTab(tsLogin); // slides left
```

and later

```
ChangeTab(tsNewTemplate, True); // slides right
// stuff
ChangeTab(tsLogin, True); // slides right
```

My Tabcontrol app. is much more complex than this simple 3 level example. I want to be able to control the direction of the shift on command.

The ChangeTabAction1.Direction indicator doesn't have any meaning in the usual sense. You can't set it to Reverse and think that means the opposite of normal. Reverse *becomes* Normal immediately after `executetarget` and vice-versa.

```
procedure TfrmMain.ChangeTab(TargetTab: TTabItem; Reverse: Boolean = False);
begin
    // This keeps the slide direction going the same way
    // It cancels out the automatic reversal of direction
    if ChangeTabAction1.Direction = TTabTransitionDirection.Normal then
      ChangeTabAction1.Direction := TTabTransitionDirection.Reversed
    else
      ChangeTabAction1.Direction := TTabTransitionDirection.Normal;
```

Perhaps, if someone can tell me what the Embarcadero designers were thinking here, then I can follow their design idea instead of trying to work around it.

Comment: I just tested with XE8 and cannot reproduce this behaviour. If the new TabIndex is less than the current the transition is a slide from left to right and a similar behaviour the other way round. The TabAction.Direction is never touched. Cannot check with XE7 in the moment.

Comment: JFTR, TTabTransitionDirection.Normal means tabs with a lower index are changed to with a left-to-right transition and tabs with a higher index are change to with a right-to-left transition. So you should only change Direction when you don't want this behaviour.

Comment: Thanks Uwe! After 2 months of development on this app., the used tabsheets (there are lots of unused one's, scheduled for deletion) were in a different order than they are displayed! The solution was to re-order the tabsheets using the PageControl Items Editor. After this, the transitions behaved as you predicted. I'd upvote you if I could.

Comment: Seems that my comment qualifies for an answer, so then.

Answer (score 2):

TTabTransitionDirection.Normal means that changes to tabs with a lower index are done with a left-to-right transition while changes to tabs with a higher index are done with a right-to-left transition. TTabTransitionDirection.Reversed means, well, the reverse.